# Get remaining dates from Array

Tags: php

I have one leave array,(retrive from table)

```
$leavearray=array("2019-10-22","2019-10-23","2019-10-25","2019-10-26","2019-10-28","2019-10-30");
```

If I give 2,it should return next 2nd working day-2019-10-27
If I give 1,it should return next 1st working day-2019-10-24
Can you help me to get this.

```
$priority=2;
$date="2019-10-22";
echo $this->checknextdate($date,$priority);

function checknextdate($date,$priority){ 
    $leavearray=array("2019-10-22","2019-10-23","2019-10-25","2019-10-26","2019-10-28","2019-10-30");
    do{
       if(in_array($date,$leavearray))
       {
           $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date.'+1 day'));
       }else{
           return $date;
           $checkok=1;
           exit();
       }
     } while ($checkok==1); 
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the do loop here? Kinda seems redundent

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this, using your original code, although this might not be the perfect solution:

```
$priority = 2;
$date = "2019-10-22";
echo checknextdate($date,$priority);

function checknextdate($date, $priority){ 
    $leavearray = array("2019-10-22","2019-10-23","2019-10-25","2019-10-26","2019-10-28","2019-10-30");

    do{
       $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . '+1 day'));

        if (!in_array($date, $leavearray)) {
           $priority--;
        }
    } while ($priority > 0); 

    return $date;
}
```